Inwardly nodded appreciatively?
I'm looking for a single-word synonym or at least less clunky version of the title. Outwardly the body language would be a kind of half-smile, a slight compressive lengthening of the mouth, widening of the eyes and one or two slight nods, and the message is "not too shabby" or "by George, he's got it!", but inwardly, perhaps in writing — say in writing a review.
Some rejected possibilities:
appreciate — seems to me perfunctory, almost empty, and likely prefacing a criticism: I appreciate that you're trying to help, but...
acknowledge — somewhat more sincere than "appreciate", but grudging: I acknowledge that he's a straight A student, but...
Maybe these words need embellishment: genuinely appreciate, appreciatively acknowledge ?
I was led here by some near answers to similar questions and thought it might be worth asking again.

Your best bet would be to rely on an adverb to get across the sentiment you're trying to express. I don't see any problem with genuinely appreciate/ wholeheartedly acknowledge. There can't be a single word for everything in a language, can there? And I don't see how it's clunky.

I doubt that there's a single-word synonym. '... nodded inwardly in appreciation', though lengthier, sounds less clunky ... but this now becomes style/writing advice, which probably belongs on Writing.SE (style guidance not being on-topic on ELU).

When nodding shows appreciation, no need to narrate the meaning, because of show don't tell.

So is there a visible sign, or not?


Inwardly nodded appreciatively

All nods are exterior, and the verb acknowledges this. If you depart into metaphor, then the adverb "inwardly" will have to be used.
You have a verb and two separate adjectives: you are not going to find a verb (and it would have to be a verb) that encompasses this extremely specific and metaphoric action.
Your quest is given as "I'm looking for a single-word synonym" but there isn't one.

With your examples, what you are looking for is proud or one of its synonyms. I don't know if there is a word for passive/silent pride. Maybe pleased, honored, or satisfied. None of these have to have any outward expression.
